# Jest - cannot find the tests

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am unable to run my jest test for some weird reason. Am I missing out something here?

**I have tried both __test__ &  __tests__**

> **Folder structure** :

[image]

> **Package.json** :

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest watchAll --no-cache"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./src/test/setup.ts"
    ]
  },
```

> **Error** :

```sh
> auth@1.0.0 test E:\cultor-microservices\auth
> jest watchAll --no-cache

No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In E:\cultor-microservices\auth
  15 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 1 match
  testPathIgnorePatterns: \\node_modules\\ - 15 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern: watchAll - 0 matches
```

Comment: You can see in the output what it's looking for: `**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)`. `__tests__` should work, `__test__` won't, so give a [mre] of something that should work.

Answer (score 1):

This was such a silly mistake, I forgot "--" infront of watchAll in the test script in
**package.json**:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --poll src/index.ts",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"      // <-- here 
  }
```